# Ender 3 v2 X-axis home fails

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, lcd-screen, x-axis, direct-drive

I have a problem. I upgraded my Ender 3 v2 for direct drive and added CR Touch. Updated software to bugfix-JyersUI v2.0.1. Now if I turn on my printer first homing X-axis moves to the left clicks one time (usually clicks 2 times) to endstop and that's it. Every after homing X-axis moves right. Changed endstop with a different endstop; same problem. Changed firmware with less possibility firmware and homing is successful.

Comment: This sounds like two different problems: X-axis homing problem and an LCD display problem. If this is correct, please [edit] your question to one then create a second "question" to address the second problem. I have used JyerUI so I can offer help but this sounds like 2 different problems.

Comment: Lcd display problem does not bother me. Homing issue is the main problem. If u can help me with homing problem that will be great.

Comment: My problem was with the Z-axis so I don't know if this will actually help (that's why I'm writing as a comment). Check your wiring from the CR Touch to the mainboard. I had a misconnection on my printer and was causing the Z-axis not to lower to the buildplate.